# Evaluating an infinite square root

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, nested-radicals

How do I evaluate the square root: $$\sqrt{2013+276\sqrt{2027+278\sqrt{2041+280\cdots}}}$$
I have tried creating two arithmetic sequences such that $$a_n  = 1999+14n$$

$$b_n = 274+2n$$
so the square root simplifies to 
$$\sqrt{a_1+b_1\sqrt{a_2+b_2\sqrt{a_3+b_3\cdots}}}$$
But I get stuck there. Any help/hints is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ozo: And $c_{n+1}=\frac{c_n^2-a_n}{b_n}$, so you can choose _any_ sufficiently large $c_1$ and extend it to a sequence of $c_i$s that satisfies these relations. That's not really helpful for finding the value sought here (which I assume is the limit of the _truncated_ nested radicals).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't understand what you mean by truncated, but it's an infinite nested radical, where there's an infinite amount of terms.

Comment: Check some of the question listed under "Related" and see whether there's anything you can use there. Or search the site for "nested radical", "nested square root", ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just a special case of the Ramanujan [nested radical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical):
$$a+n+x=\sqrt{ax+(n+a)^2 +x\sqrt{a(x+n)+(n+a)^2+(x+n) \sqrt{\mathrm{\cdots}}}},$$
with the choices $a=7,x=276,n=2$, that ensure convergence to $285$.

Comment: How do you prove this identity?